# Set KendoDatepicker min date in open event

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to display past date in kendo datepicker input ,but want disable the past dates in the calender. For example , I am getting date value as 1st Oct from DB. SO I want to display the same in the date input but when user opens the kendo datepicker , i want to disable the past dates as part of validation. I tried with min: new Date() of kendo datepicker but in this case i am not able to display my data from DB

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Could you try this: .Min(DateTime.Today)

Comment: Any luck - did you find a way ?

Comment: Yeah I tried , but its not working.

Comment: Does the edited solution works for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/ATmHG/4/

```
var todaysDate = new Date();
var pastDate = new Date(2013, 1, 1);

var dp = $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
    value: pastDate,
     min: pastDate,
     open: function(e) {
         if ( dp.min() == pastDate)  {
            dp.value(todaysDate);
            dp.min(todaysDate);
         }
      }
}).data("kendoDatePicker");
```

Comment: Its not working. My requirement is ,past date should be disabled.

Comment: I have improved the solution little bit, please give it a go !